# Swift/iOS: Capture only the previous 10 seconds of a video recording

Tags: ios, swift, video-capture

I want to constantly record a video stream using my iOS device, but given some action (Double tap screen etc.) I want to capture the 10 seconds prior to me invoking the action.

I am not sure how to do this without storing the whole video stream and then taking just the last 10 seconds of video.

Comment: You are correct, the only way to get video from the past is to record it while it is still in the present.

Comment: @Dom Bryan were you able to solve the problem ?

Comment: @radioaktiv unfortunately not, and my work has moved away from this so I haven't explored it any further. I may re-visit this soon to work it out :)

Comment: @DomBryan I got it working by using ffmpeg library https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg and `-sseof` command of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code may be it's work for you

```
   let session = AVCaptureSession()
   let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

    movieOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: 10, preferredTimescale: 1)
    if session.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
        session.addOutput(movieOutput)
    }
```

Comment: I believe this will capture a 10 second video but from the point in which I start the recording. I am aiming to start a recording, potentially have it going for 10 minutes and then just capture the 10 seconds of 9:50 - 10:00 mins with some sort of action. Thanks for your input though